# Gnuplot 3d plotting --- making plot size set to terminal size

Tags: plot, gnuplot

Okay I have been working with gnuplot for sometime and have one question. I cannot make the plot size equal to the terminal size I set it to. There are examples of setting 
Lmargin,rmargin, tmargin  and bmargin to 0 but this doesn't work on 'splot' which is 3d plotting. So I want to know what is the workaround for it?

Answer (score 2):

For color maps you can use `plot ... with image` instead of `set pm3d map` if you want to use the margin options as usual. For 3d plots, as you say, the margin options are not available, and a workaround would be to shift the position of your graph and scale it. To do that, use `set origin` and `set size` respectively.

For instance, `splot x*y` yields the following:

[image]

If you want to reduce the margins while keeping the same overall terminal size, you can try:

```
set origin -0.1,-0.1
set size 1.2,1.2
splot x*y
```

which gives you:

[image]

You probably get the idea. Note I set a background color just so you can visualize where the margins lie because of the white background in the Stack Overflow website.

Comment: sure thnks for heads up!